# Как умножить "80,11.руб" на "44" в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```python
import requests
Recoil = 44
url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=5&country=us&appid=730&market_hash_name=Recoil%20Case&format=json"
r = requests.get(url)
Recoil_p = r.json()["median_price"]
print(float(Recoil)*float(Recoil_p))
```

Из ссылки я получаю цену предмета, предположим 88,11 руб., мне нужно эту цену умножить на количество предметов (например 44). Цена приходит в переменную именно в таком формате (88,11 руб.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно выделить первое слово через метод `split()`, заменить запятую на точку через `replace()` и потом уже преобразовать во `float`:

```py
print(float(Recoil) * float(Recoil_p.split()[0].replace(',', '.')))
```